# jquery datepicker disable specific days and dates dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, json, datepicker

I would like to block specific dates and week days dynamically from MySQL database records. I have done to some extent and not able to proceed further.

```
json_encode(array("days"=>$days_off,"dates"=>$resultarr))
```

The above will output the following:

```
{"days":["0","1","1","1","1","1","0"],"dates":["2015-06-01","2015-06-02","2015-06-03","2015-06-04","2015-06-05"
,"2015-06-06","2015-07-09","2015-07-10","2015-07-28","2015-07-29","2015-07-30","2015-07-31"]}
```

And in the front end, the jquery written in this way:

```
success: function(data){
    var dateToday = new Date();
    var ndata = $.parseJSON(data);
    if ($('#datepicker').length) $("#datepicker").datepicker({  
        minDate: dateToday, firstDay: 1, //endDate: '+0m',
        dateFormat: "DD d MM yy", showOtherMonths:false,
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ 
            var day = date.getDay();
            var selected = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate');
            return [ndata[day] !=0, ""];
        }                   
    });             
}
```

The above will block only the days(monday-sunday) but not able to block specific dates which I get from above json data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the date is the same as any of the ones passed in your JSON. It could be done like this:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) { 

    //Check if it's a forbidden day of the week.
    var day = date.getDay();
    var okDay = (ndata.days[day] != 0);

    //Check if it's a forbidden date.
    var formatted_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date)
    var okDate = ($.inArray(formatted_date, ndata.dates) == -1);

    //Only return true if both day of week and date are allowed.
    return [okDay && okDate]

}
```

Please note that I have not tested this code. Also, I changed from `ndata[day]` to `ndata.days[day]` since that seemed to be more inline with your JSON, but I might be wrong there. [Here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) is the documentation on `.inArray()`, and [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is the documentation on `datepicker.formatDate()`.